# Is it possible to have a property that is IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, ienumerable

I have a class that's `IEnumerable<T>` where I want to have different properties that provides a filtered `IEnumerable<T>` access.

So for instance:

```
class Shape
   ShapeType = Box/Sphere/Pyramid

class ShapeCollection : IEnumerable<Shape>
{
   public IEnumerable<Shape> OnlyBox
   {
       foreach(var s in this)
       {
           if (s.ShapeType == Box)
               yield return s;
       }
   }
}
```

Is this how it should be? Just not sure, about it completely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, but you might want to rewrite it as

```
public IEnumerable<Shape> OnlyBox
{
    get { return this.Where(x => x.ShapeType == ShapeType.Box); }
}
```

which does the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this was a bit flaky in my mind. Now I can see it clearly.

Answer (score 4):

```
class ShapeCollection : IEnumerable<Shape>
{
   public IEnumerable<Shape> OnlyBoxes
   {
       get { return this.Where(s => s.ShapeType == Box); }
   }
}
```

You were missing the `get`/parenthesis to make it a method. Also what is `Box`, did you mean `ShapeType.Box`? Also maybe rename it to `OnlyBoxes`, seems more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks I voted you. I wrote the code like that because I wasn't using VS and didn't want to write the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, that should work (as far as I can see) even though @mquander's solution might be a tad more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid, but redundant I think.  If you want to expose a strongly-typed list of Shapes:

```
public class Shape
{

}

public class SomethingThatHasShapes
{
   public List<Shape> Shapes { get; set; }
   public Boxes
   {
      get { return Shapes.Where(s => s.ShapeType = ShapeType.Box); }
   }  


}
```

The `List<T>` class implements IEnumerable.

Comment: The downside of this is that it exposes your list to outside influences.

Comment: You need a return type on the your second property.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I believe your `OnlyBox` property is redundant. Because the users of your class will always have the option to use Linq like the following with the same performance. So unless you can do it better than the Linq methods, I think it is fine to leave it to the user of the class like:

```
var filtered = shapeCol.Where(s => s.ShapeType == Box);
```

But if you want a property, instead of:

```
foreach(var s in this)
{
    if (s.ShapeType == Box)
        yield return s;
}
```

you could write:

```
return this.Where(s => s.ShapeType == Box);
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea was because this is simplified but in reality the code to filter is very ugly because this is a wrapper for unmanaged class. So wanted to make it a bit more high level for users and myself.

Answer (score 1):

A more LINQ like fashion would be providing a method for your Collection:

```
public IEnumerable<Shape> Boxes()
{
    return this.Where(ss => ss.ShapeType == ShapeType.Box);
}
```

Or just having users do a Where clause:

```
// gather boxes
var query = from shape in shapes
            where shape.ShapeType == ShapeType.Box
            select shape;
```

Otherwise, nothing wrong with IEnumerable as a property (keeping in mind properties should be so simple they rarely throw exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

Yep. What you have is good. You can do convert to lambda-based if you prefer its expressiveness, though the lambda version can *sometimes* be less performant (not so much that I'd change a lambda version to 2.0 style unless it proved problematic, but enough that I wouldn't change a perfectly good 2.0 style to lambda-based unless it made it a **lot** more expressive).